# Why apktool 2.2.2 build fails?

Tags: windows, apktool

De-compiling has successful done, but when I build it has error, see below link

https://gist.github.com/ronjunelopez/91d5cd0d9654adea632b17631971e912

Answer (score 0):

The logs that you have shared shows there's some problem with recompiling resources, as that's when the recompiling stops. If you are not changing anything in resource file or you don't want to use those resources, you can decompile your apk with this command:

```
apktool d -f -r myapk.apk
```

here -f if to force the replacement of previously decompiled apk and -r it to tell the decompiler not to decompile resources and once you are done, you can recompile your apk normally.